# Request POST method in ajax to an cookie.php file

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I want to sent an request with POST method to a file cookie.php to plot my form in the index. 
My php file looks like this `

```
$cookie_name="User";
$cookie_value="John";
$days=365;

setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value,time()+($days*30),"/");

?>
```

and my Ajax coding looks like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#cookie-form").click(function(){

$.ajax({

method:"POST";
url:"cookie.php";

.success(function(data){
$("#cookie_name").append($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])
}
}


}

$("#check-cookie-form").click(function(){

$.ajax({

method:"POST";
url:"check_cookie.php";
}
}

});
```

Comment: Please state your issue and format your code properly.

Comment: So what's the question? Also if its not an http only cookie just set it client side, no need for ajax

Comment: `.append($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])` makes no sense. You can't jump freely between client side JavaScript and server side PHP. You have to properly construct and read your requests and responses.

Comment: There are problems with your `Ajax coding`,

Comment: I want to plot a form that when i click a button in the form is comes the Cookie name. Maybe .append is wrong. But do you maybe know how it can be?